# How do I replace the console message without it disappearing so fast?

Tags: javascript, timeout, stopwatch

I tried to make a stopwatch in the console, but the message kept on clearing before I had time to read it.
I tried increasing how long the Timeout function would go, but for some reason, it didn't make a difference.
Can somebody help me with making the messages not clear so fast?

```
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("1");
}, 1000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
},1099);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("2"); 
}, 2000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 2099);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("3");
}, 3000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 3099);
```

Comment: you need to use some promise techique... ( async, await...)

Answer (score 1):

second argument to settimeout represents time in milliseconds.  1000ms = 1seconds. consider this.  Maybe you should increase the time it takes to run the console.clear(), base on your code it executes after 2 and 3 seconds.

@Mr.Buscuit, consider using the setInveral function,

```
        let sec = 0;
        setInterval(function () {
            console.clear();
            console.log(sec);
            sec++;
        }, 1000);
```

This log a new number to the log every second.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, this is a nice short answer. This would be greater with a code example.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

1- first line of code you tell your browser to execute that function which print on console number "1"

2- second line you tell browser after ***99ms*** (from beginning of timer) NOT ***1099ms*** clear the console

Why `99ms`? because All Timer API(Browser API) e.g (setTimeout, setInterval) works at same time, all of these functions that you do, they have a one(only one) timer, hence that means when timer reach at `1000ms`, second `setTimeout` that you determined its timer with `1099ms` reached at `1000ms` as well (one timer), hence still `99ms` remaining from `1099ms`

**Summary**
Imagine there is one big timer is running for all functions, this means if we have 2 `setTimeout` with time we specified `1000ms` (2 function with same time) this is not means after finish first function that need `1000ms`, second starts `setTimeout` timer that will begin from scratch, hence need `1000ms` again with total latency `2000ms`, No, this is wrong, two functions will work together

very good resource for understand this concept : [Async Concept](https://dev.to/lydiahallie/javascript-visualized-promises-async-await-5gke)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the words you're using, but I kind of have an idea of what you are saying.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I updated my answer, see if it is a clear or still not.
Sorry for corruption.